# Two X-screens, how to get a window manager on second screen?

Tags: unity, xorg, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. I have two X-screens, on separate graphics cards. I believe the screens are `:0.0` and `:0.1`.

The problem is that, at startup, only my primary screen has a window manager, with Unity/compiz on it.

I have tried the following:

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 compiz --replace &
```

which has the effect of removing all window decorations from my primary display and removes the unity launcher. Furthermore, all keyboard input is directed permanently to my second display!

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 metacity --replace &
```

In the second display is able to restore functionality, with both displays operational, but no Unity, and no window decorations on second display.

I've tried several combinations of `:0.0`, `:0.1`, `unity` `metacity` `gnome-wm` and `compiz` with `--replace`, but haven't found any way to work it. What I need, is both displays to have a window manager, and to have Compositing to enabled on the primary display.

PS:

I have decided on 2 X-screens is because the monitors are driven by two different Nvidia graphics cards, so from what I gather compositing would require separate X-screens.

I have previously had success with `gnome-classic` + `Xinerama`, which allows a single large X-screen covering both monitors but with no compositing.

---

**PS**

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` has:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1920 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

And

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +1080+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Where `Device0` is a `"Quadro FX 580"` and `Device1` is a `"GeForce 8600 GT"`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can run the same window manager at the same time, on the same user, on two X servers. At least you can't do it with most feature-rich wms.

Try running `xfwm4` (XFCE window manager) as your secondary wm.

PS: I remember having fun with a compositing enabled Xinerama on a dual card ATI config and `xmonad` in the past, so I would advice keeping experimenting with that if you are using `>=3` monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You *need* Xinerama for this.

What are the 2 graphics cards? Are they close enough that you can either run the same driver for both, or totally different drivers?

E.g. on the machine I am using right now, I have 3 screens on 2 dissimilar cards:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K620] (rev a2)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
```

So long as I use the Nouveau FOSS drivers, this works fine and I have accelerated X.org on both.